# How to provide two Integer values and emit one String

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am learning RxAndroid api, so I created an example where the input is two integers and the output should be a string containing these integers. for example,
for 1 and two the output should be "1,2" and so on.

in the below code is my attempts to achieve what I am planning to do, but I need guiding and help please.

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private EditText mEditTextValue1 = null;
private EditText mEditTextValue2 = null;
private Button mButtonStartAsyncTask = null;
private rx.Observable<Integer> mAsyncObservable = null;
private TextView mTextViewProcessedValue = null;

Subscriber<String> mAsyncSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCompleted(mAsyncSubscriber)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError(mAsyncSubscriber)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String next) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onNext(mAsyncSubscriber)");

        mTextViewProcessedValue.setText();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    mEditTextValue1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValue1);
    mEditTextValue2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValue2);
    mButtonStartAsyncTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartAsyncTask);

    mButtonStartAsyncTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer value1 = Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValue1.getText().toString());
            Integer value2 = Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValue2.getText().toString());

            mAsyncObservable = rx.Observable.just(value1, value2)
                    .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                    .doOnNext(items-> {
                        mTextViewProcessedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProcessedValue);

                        return value1 + ", " + value2;
                    })

                    .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            Log.w(TAG, "doOnCompleted");
                        }
                    })

            //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((Action1<? super Integer>) mAsyncSubscriber);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Is the delay necessary? Without the delay, you can easily do the concatenation with `TextUtils.join(",", values)`. I'm a huge fan of rx... but in this scenario `TextUtils` is less lines of code, is more readable, and it avoids the rx overhead.

Answer (score 0):

i'm new with RxJava too ... this might be what you want

```
io.reactivex.Observable.range(1, 100).subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            list.add(integer);
            if (list.size() % 2 == 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onNext: couple int :" + list.get(0) + " ," + list.get(1));
                list.clear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

if you want to emit two values together you may emit a array or list or Pojo.

using [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) example:

```
  io.reactivex.Observable<Integer> s1 = io.reactivex.Observable.range(1, 100);
  io.reactivex.Observable<Integer> s2 = io.reactivex.Observable.range(-100, 100);
  io.reactivex.Observable.zip(s1, s2, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String >() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Integer i1, Integer i2) throws Exception {
                    return i1 + " ," + i2;
                }})
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thanks but i do not want do it that way...i want to use the operators and the methods affered by AxAndroid api

Comment: you may take a look at zip operator. i guess that's what u want

Comment: would you please clarify? what is i1 and i2

Comment: sure it's a BiFunction that takes two integer as input and returns a string as output.

Answer (score 0):

The operator you want to use really depends on how many numbers you will have, how many products you want, and what you want to do with the final answer. For this example, we'll use [`scan(...)`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html)

> apply a function to each item emitted by an Observable, sequentially, and emit each successive value

```
Observable.just(value1, value2)
    .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .scan("", (string, integer) -> string + "," + integer)
```

The above will emit once: `"{value1},{value2}"`. 
If you add a third value, it will emit twice :  `"{value1},{value2}"` and  `"{value1},{value2},{value3}"`

Answer (score 0):

Looking on code what you trying achieve is reading from 2 fields on button click and emit them to observable, is it correct?

Please check this project to replace listener with rxjava bindings:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding. Then code would be something like this:

```
       RxView.clicks(button)
            .map(event -> {
                Integer value1 = Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValue1.getText().toString());
                Integer value2 = Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValue2.getText().toString());
                return value1 + "," + value2;
            })                
            .subscribe(combinedIntegers ->
                    mTextViewProcessedValue.setText(combinedIntegers));
```

Comment: I don't think you really need a another thread for this. Keep the whole thing on the main thread perhaps?

Comment: @masp Yes, that true can be avoided. Fixed an answer